# How to install symfony's http foundation in Joomla4 and autload all classes?

Tags: joomla, typo3, phar, symfony-http-foundation, joomla4

After upgrading to Joomla4.3 from Joomla 3.10.11, I am getting typo3 PharStreamWrapper uncaught exception:

`Fatal error: Uncaught TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\Exception: Unexpected file extension in "phar://httpful.phar/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php" in /var/www/html/asms/libraries/vendor/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/Interceptor/PharExtensionInterceptor.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/asms/libraries/vendor/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/Behavior.php(72): TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\Interceptor\PharExtensionInterceptor->assert() #1 /var/www/html/asms/libraries/vendor/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/Manager.php(110): TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\Behavior->assert() #2 /var/www/html/asms/libraries/vendor/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/PharStreamWrapper.php(421): TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\Manager->assert() #3 /var/www/html/asms/libraries/vendor/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/PharStreamWrapper.php(410): TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\PharStreamWrapper->assert() #4 [internal function]: TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\PharStreamWrapper->url_stat() #5`

Symfony's httpfoundation is not installed. What is the correct way to install it in Joomla4 and how to autoload all its classes?